# When getting user input, I want to check for two values, however, the code I using keeps looping

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
action = input('Please enter add or del.\n')
def check_greeting1(action):
    while True:
        if action == '':
            action = input("please enter add or del.\n")
        else:
            break
```

When getting user input, I want to check for two values, however, the code I use keeps looping.

Comment: Seems to work for me, given that `check_greeting1(action)` is called. It's not very clear what the expected behaviour is. You _do_ want it to loop if action is blank, right? (and by extension, if action is not "add" or "del").

Comment: What is your desired input/output?

Answer (score 1):

Please do it. This function asks the user repeatedly until the user enters a valid input value.

```
def get_input():
    while True:
        inputstr = input('Please enter add or del: ')
        if inputstr == 'add' or inputstr == 'del'
            return inputstr
        else:
            print('Wrong Input!')
```

Answer (score -1):

Put the `action = input('Please enter add or del.\n')` into while loop.

```py
def check_greeting1():
    while True:
        action = input('Please enter add or del.\n')
        if not action:
            action = input("please enter add or del.\n")
        else:
            break
```

Comment: There is no need to add `action = input("please enter add or del.\n")` in the if statement.